# Norlund-Euler statistical convergence in intuitionistic fuzzy normed space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

In the definition of $(N,p,q)(E,q)$-summable with respect to the intuitionistic fuzzy norm, $\frac{1}{R_n} \sum \mu (p_{n-k}q_k \frac{1}{(1+q)^k} \sum \left( \begin{array}{c} k \\ v \end{array} \right) q^{k-v} (x_v-l),t) > 1-\epsilon$,
does one have to put the modulus for $(x_v-l)$? Meaning should it be $(x_v-l)$ or $|x_v - l|$?